# consecutive matches in regex (R)

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to write a regex expression (under R) that matches all the words containing 3 letters in this text:

```
tex= "As you are now so once were we"
```

My first attempt is to select words containing 3 letters surrounded by spaces:

```
matches=str_match_all(tex," [a-z]{3} ")
```

It's supposed to match **" you "**, **" are "** and **" now "**. But, since some of these spaces are shared between the matched strings, I only get **" you "** and **" now "**.

Is there a way to fix this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It may be better to use a word boundary (`\\b`)

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(tex,"\\b[a-z]{3}\\b")[[1]]
#   [,1] 
#[1,] "you"
#[2,] "are"
#[3,] "now"
```

Or we can also use `str_extract`

```
str_extract_all(tex,"\\b[a-z]{3}\\b")[[1]]
#[1] "you" "are" "now"
```

Comment: I only added `library(stringr)`. Didn't remove aything - I promise :-)

Comment: @RHertel Thanks, then it got removed automatically.

Comment: Looking at the revision history it seems like I did remove something, but I actually did not. It must be some kind of bug, presumably we were editing the post at the same time and the result was conflicting.

Comment: @RHertel Yes, that seems like the logical conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tex= "As you are now so once were we"
```

Base R function

```
regmatches(tex , gregexpr('\\b[a-z]{3}\\b' , tex))[[1]]

 [1] "you" "are" "now"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

This works because `\b` doesn't match the whitespace/punctuation itself, but rather the *position* of the word boundary, so the spaces are not included in the match.

You also want to include A-Z in the character range to include uppercase letters.

This was taken from the examples in http://regexr.com/, they have a "4 letter words" example.